# Sending 2 objects in 1 POST request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular and trying to send a request (using `$resource`) to an external API but I have the data I need to send in 2 different objects, while I currently only send 1. The API requires user specific actions to include an `auth_token` with every request.

Without the `auth_token`, the request would look like this:

```
APIShop.reg(Cart.data,
function(success) {}, 
function(failure) {}
);
```

`APIShop` looks like this:

```
app.provider('APIShop', function(API_URL) {
    this.$get = ['$resource', function($resource) {
        var Campaign = $resource(API_URL.url + API_URL.loc + ':service/:action/', {service: '@service', action: '@action'},   { 
            'reg':  {method:'POST', isArray: false, params: {service: 'account', action: 'order'}},
            'update':  {method:'PUT', isArray: false, params: {service: 'account', action: 'order'}}
        });
        return Campaign;
    }];
});
```

`Cart.data` is an object that looks like: `{country: 'US', city: 'Seattle, WA'}`

but I need to also add `{auth_token: '432078e36c7a42e3c6febdac95f38c1549de6218'}` from the `User` object in the same request. The immediate solution would probably be to add the `auth_token` field to the `Cart` object, but as I'm storing this data in the application in various models `User`, `ShoppingCart`, etc, I'd like to keep auth_token in the `User` object.

I tried doing

```
APIShop.reg(Cart.data, User.auth_token
function(success) {}, 
function(failure) {}
);
```

didn't expect it to work, and it didn't. The auth_token ends up showing as a `Request Payload` instead of `Query String Parameters`.

I also don't want to send something like `{country: Cart.data.country, city: Cart.data.city, auth_token: '432078e36c7a42e3c6febdac95f38c1549de6218'}` directly (as opposed to sending the object) as that will become a maintenance nightmare sooner or later.

How would I go about sending both pieces of information without adding the token to `Cart` (since it'll mean I need to add it to every object going forward), or listing all the fields of the object?

Answer (score 0):

Refactor APIShop to receive an array:

```
APIShop.reg([Cart.data, User.auth_token],
function(success) {}, 
function(failure) {}
);
```

Or refactor it to receive a mapping object:

```
APIShop.reg({ data : Cart.data, auth : User.auth_token },
function(success) {}, 
function(failure) {}
);
```

Comment: I just tried updating `APIShop` to: `'reg':  {method:'POST', isArray: true, params: {service: 'account', action: 'order'}}` (`isArray` is changed to `true`). Now everything shows up as `Request Payload` instead of `Query String Parameters`.

Comment: Since I don't have control over the external API, is there no way to get Angular to throw away the `[` and `]` from the array and send the contents only?